# TargetUnits in BarLegend

Tags: plotting, legending

Is there any way to get the '%' in the BarLegend to be black instead of light gray?

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendFunction -> "Panel",
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Monaco", FontSize -> 18, 
   FontColor -> Black}],
FrameStyle -> Black,
TargetUnits -> "%"]
```

[image: ContourPlot with barLegend and Units (in different style)]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in MMA 13.0.1 any longer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cp = ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendFunction -> "Panel",
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Monaco", FontSize -> 18,
 FontColor -> Black}], FrameStyle -> Black, TargetUnits -> "%"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`FullForm[cp[[2,1]]]` gives the code that constructs the legend. Inspecting that code we find the piece that we need to modify:

> `` Rule[Charting`TickAnnotations,
>   Style[QuantityForm["Percent", "PlotLabel"], GrayLevel[0.7`]]] ``

So using the following replacement rule

```
graytoblack = Rule[Charting`TickAnnotations, Style[q_,GrayLevel[_]]]:>
    Rule[Charting`TickAnnotations,   Style[q,GrayLevel[0]]];
```

to post-process `cp`

```
cp/.graytoblack
```

we get:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You could have used the simpler ``cp /. GrayLevel[0.7`]->GrayLevel[0]``; but this would have changed all ``GrayLevel[0.7`]`` elements, not just the "%" in the legend.